# How to mount a hardware locked usb pendrive on a mac?

Tags: mac, usb, usb-flash-drive

I recently got this pendrive from my bank. It's a 4GB drive - but all that shows up on my mac is a 2MB partition containing a file `logintool.exe`. I confirmed that on windows I can login - but unfortunately not unlock the drive permanently.

I'm wondering if I could unlock it somehow so I would be able to also use it with my mac.

When I look at it in disk-utility I only "2.1MG Generic Flash Disk Media", readonly - nothing else.

Other stuff that might be helpful from the hardware info:
Flash Disk
Product-ID: 0x2095
Producer-ID:    0x1e3d  (Chipsbrand Technologies (HK) Co., Limited)

Answer (score 1):

Try [wine](http://winehq.org). It might work.

> Wine lets you run Windows software on other operating systems. With Wine, you can install and run these applications just like you would in Windows.